# Find Types in All Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, reflection, types

I need to look for specific types in all assemblies in a web site or windows app, is there an easy way to do this?  Like how the controller factory for ASP.NET MVC looks across all assemblies for controllers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

There are two steps to achieve this:

- The `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` gives you all assemblies loaded in the current application domain.
- The `Assembly` class provides a `GetTypes()` method to retrieve all types within that particular assembly.

Hence your code might look like this:

```
foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes())
    {
        // ... do something with 't' ...
    }
}
```

To look for specific types (e.g. implementing a given interface, inheriting from a common ancestor or whatever) you'll have to filter-out the results. In case you need to do that on multiple places in your application it's a good idea to build a helper class providing different options. For example, I've commonly applied namespace prefix filters, interface implementation filters, and inheritance filters.

For detailed documentation have a look into MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx).

Comment: Of course, if you were going to do some filtering on those types and assemblies, you'd use LINQ, right? ;)

Comment: @Niall Connaughton That's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I've found situations when doing this causes an exception, turned out to be because my application was generating dynamic assemblies,  just a gotcha to be aware of.  You can identify the dynamic assemblies and skip them like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423733/how-to-tell-if-a-net-assembly-is-dynamic - if it does cause a problem

Comment: Note that assemblies are only loaded on demand, i.e. when they are used for the first time.

Answer (score 41):

LINQ solution with check to see if the assembly is dynamic:

```
/// <summary>
/// Looks in all loaded assemblies for the given type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fullName">
/// The full name of the type.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// The <see cref="Type"/> found; null if not found.
/// </returns>
private static Type FindType(string fullName)
{
    return
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.FullName.Equals(fullName));
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Easy using Linq:

```
IEnumerable<Type> types =
            from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            from t in a.GetTypes()
            select t;

foreach(Type t in types)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Most commonly you're only interested in the assemblies that are visible from the outside. Therefor you need to call **GetExportedTypes()** But besides that a **ReflectionTypeLoadException** can be thrown. The following code takes care of these situations.

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> FindTypes(Func<Type, bool> predicate)
{
    if (predicate == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));

    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        if (!assembly.IsDynamic)
        {
            Type[] exportedTypes = null;
            try
            {
                exportedTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes();
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
            {
                exportedTypes = e.Types;
            }

            if (exportedTypes != null)
            {
                foreach (var type in exportedTypes)
                {
                    if (predicate(type))
                        yield return type;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I still get the `could not load type exception` with your code.