# How to get the subclass type just by examining the generic argument on its parent class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, reflection, asp.net-web-api2

Example:

```
    public class MyClass : AbstractClass<UserDTO>
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
        }

        public string Property1 { get; set; }

        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }
```

**Is it even possible to get the type of MyClass just by examining the UserDTO object? If yes, how?
TIA.**

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking something like:

> Is there a way within `AbstractClass<T>` that, where the type of `T` is `UserDTO`, I can determine the type of class `X` where `class X : AbstractClass<UserDTO>`

If this is indeed your question, then the short answer is "yes". The path to achieving it is a little convoluted though.

First step, obtain a list of all the types in your system, using eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/4692463/7122.

Next step, for each type use the `BaseType` property to get its parent type. If that type is `AbstractClass` then examine its `GenericTypeArguments` property to see if that is `UserDTO`. If it is, that's your type.

More than one class may inherit from `AbstractClass<UserDTO>` though, so you'd have to examine all types to check for that, rather than stopping at the first match.

Comment: You can refer to Stu's answer below for what I meant. Ok, I will rephrase my question.

Comment: @DennisLaping, I've updated my answer to answer the question I think you are asking.

Comment: Yes, I see. I will try your way. Thanks, David.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of a UserDTO class and nothing else then I can't see any way that you'd be able to see the owning instance or type of MyClass - how would you differentiate between that and a UserDTO which wasn't on a MyClass? Sorry