# Parse Server - enumerate all classes in .Net

Tags: .net, parse-platform, parse-server

I have inherited an existing Parse infrastructure setup running in Azure.  I can query the classes with no problems using ParseObject.GetQuery.  What I would like to do is to write a query to loop through all available classes but cannot see how to list the classes in the first place.  I have seen some examples using REST but am unable to get these to work.  Hopefully someone knows the .Net commands to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4692463/15393? If it's not relevant, please explain why, as I'm not sure I understand your question...

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it was not giving me anything relevant.  To hopefully clarify my question, I wish to enumerate all of the classes in a Parse Server instance.  I can quite happily query the objects within each class with no problems but all I need to do is to return a list of available classes.  This can then be passed to existing code as a parameter.

Comment: Dim query = ParseObject.GetQuery(className).Limit(1000)
Dim results As IEnumerable(Of ParseObject) = Nothing

Try
 results = Await query.FindAsync()
Catch ex As Exception
 Console.WriteLine("Connection error - trying again")
 GoTo loopy
End Try